# C++ standard library container class with a minimum size

Tags: c++, std

Say I wanted to implement a special type of container (lets say for the sake of discussion it's a vector) with a minimum size (*not* capacity).

That is, I want to inherit from std::vector and:

1. Force initializing the vector with at least 1 object of the contained class.
2. Prevent the removal of the last remaining object in the vector.

Is it possible to do this without having to override every constructor and every method that removes elements from the vector? (and possibly iterators too and other stuff)

Comment: Seems like you want an array + vector. If you simply do a vector, compile-time checking of the conditions is not possible, only runtime validation.

Comment: Every insertion/deletion has to go through the allocator's `construct()` and `destroy()`, so you can override only those. Plus override the constructors to force the initilization.

Comment: I tried something similar years ago and, after a few hours of frustration, came to the conclusion that inheriting from `std::vector` was not a good idea. In every instance I have met, making `std::vector` a *member* (rather than a base class) has avoided trouble. (This does not answer your question, of course, which is why it is a comment rather than an answer; but the Standard Template Library has too wide an interface and, apparently, too many accessory templates for comfortable inheritance.)

Comment: yep, wrap the vector inside your own class, then you can control all the operations done on it. Inheriting from standard library types is rarely a good approach

Comment: What you need is probably a `template <class T> struct S { T first; vector<T> rest; };`, with a indexing operator and iterator operations taking the offset into account.

Comment: I suspected it's probably not a good idea... but I am curious from a theoretical perspective.

Comment: Yeah, I *didn't* suspect that it was not a good idea. I had to find out the hard way. If I had a good theoretical answer I would give it, but you might ask yourself these two questions:  will your class have any virtual methods?  will its usage require runtime type identification (RTTI)?  If the answers are no and no, then C++'s inheritance mechanism was not designed with your application in mind....

Comment: On the other hand, if the answers are yes and yes, then the usual strategy would be to define a new class type A that had a narrower interface than `vector` has and included a `vector` as a private member; and then to define a new class type B that inherited from A. But that's just experience talking: like you, I lack a sound theoretical account of why inheriting from `vector` seems to meet trouble.

Comment: @ph3rin That will cause the container to become non-contiguous which seems like an unnecessary loss if you can just enforce having one element on the vector itself.

Comment: @traveh How do you intent the erasing operations to behave? E.g. `pop_back` usually doesn't perform any size validation. Calling it on an empty vector would just cause undefined behavior. What do you want to have happen in your `pop_back` implementation? Is it supposed to throw an exception instead for your implementation?

Comment: @user17732522 I was thinking about either std::runtime_error or just to return without doing anything (doesn't really matter for my purpose).